# Banach Spaces which are not $L^p$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, soft-question

Most of the times, when I think of Banach Spaces I think of $L^p$ spaces. I would like to know if there is any Banach space which can not be written as $L^p$ space. Please also indicate any applications of such spaces. Thanks

Comment: try this :http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BanachSpace.html

Comment: How about $C[0,1]$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are all sorts of weird Banach spaces.

Consider the space $c_0$ of sequences that converge to zero. This space is not (isometrically isomorphic to) an $L^p$.

In fact, if $c_0\cong L^p$, then $\ell^1=(c_0)^*=(L^p)^*=L^{q}$, with $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Therefore $q=1$, because it is the only one that is not reflexive (as $\ell^1$ is not). This implies $p=\infty$. But the dual of $L^{\infty}$ is not separable (if it is infinite dimensional), while $\ell^1$ is. Therefore $c_0$ is not an $L^p$.

There are even weirder spaces. [Tsirelson space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsirelson_space), in which you can't embed an $\ell^p$, or a $c_0$. In particular, it is not an $L^p$.

[James' space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James%27_space) is isometrically isomorphic to its double dual but not reflexive. In particular it is not an $L^p$: It can't be an $L^p$, $1<p<\infty$ because those are reflexive. It is not an $L^1$ or $L^{\infty}$ because those are not isometrically isomorphic to their double duals.

Answer (score 1):

For spaces with **APPLICATIONS**, you can try [Sobolev spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space) and things like that.

Comment: Is it possible to see if some of them is not an $L^p$? Some cases are. For example, $W^{k,2}$ are Hilbert spaces and therefore an $L^2$. Oh, [actually](https://books.google.ca/books?id=sl3qiUdrXU8C&pg=PA1363&lpg=PA1363&dq=geometry+sobolev+spaces&source=bl&ots=z89ABHikkT&sig=0Wv6qDUu6deWxSoJo_3T6f2W8OA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=x-_cVKaGD_j8sATvtoCoCw&ved=0CEMQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=geometry%20sobolev%20spaces&f=false), many of them are $L^p$'s but at least there they are saying that the cases $p=1$ and $p=\infty$ in several variables are no $L^p$.